# Post-отправка данных

Tags: javascript

Что неверно?

```
function email() {
    var data = ("#sendform")
        .serialize()
    $.post("/send.php", data, function (data) {
        $("#result")
            .html(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: Не пишите код в таком стиле дабы не попасть в ад :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`var data=$("#sendform").serialize()` не пропустил случайно $

Answer (score 0):

После

.serialize()

нужен символ ";" (точка с запятой)

Comment: не нужен вообще-то